# Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: self-signed

This error happened so I could not fixed. I should get an email but it did not send an email.

> Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
> at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {   code: 'ESOCKET',   command: 'CONN' }

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_ID,
      pass: process.env.MP,
    },
  });
  const info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '" Hey " <example2023@gmail.com>',
    to: data.to,
    subject: data.subject,
    text: data.text,
    html: data.htm,
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  console.log('Preview URl: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
});

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

Comment: Please share the error message you are getting.

Comment: I got a result in Postman like this
"1cab99e3ede107ca355f72cdc3cd00ce080d6b2a6e4818b18db26c03bda54797"
it should mean I got an email but after showing that result my project shows an error.